# Bazel: Xcode version must be specified

Tags: xcode, macos, bazel

Just upgraded to the latest version of Xcode and command line tools on Mac 10.12.16, and now I get this when I run bazel build:

```
ERROR: /private/var/etc.... : in apple_cc_toolchain rule @local_config_cc//:cc-compiler-darwin_x86_64: Xcode version must be specified to use an Apple CROSSTOOL.
```

What do I need to do to get it working again?

I'll answer myself: just run $ baze clean --expunge.

Comment: Never mind.  Just run $ bazel clean --expunge after you upgrade Xcode and tools.

Comment: Do you mind answering this yourself and marking it as accepted?

Answer (score 1):

Solution: Just run $ bazel clean --expunge after you upgrade Xcode and tools.